# Meaning of congruence notation for Bernoulli Numbers

Tags: number-theory, congruences, bernoulli-numbers

I am studying [Theorem 4(von Staudt's Theorem)](http://books.google.com/books?id=njgVUjjO-EAC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=congruence%20in%20the%20ring%20of%20p-integers&source=bl&ots=ckc4ZZftn7&sig=Hs39dQKIR0WRLKovHetowfQ8soY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GjEWVOS9GsGdyASDpYLwAw&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=von&f=false) in Borevich-Shafarevich's Number Theory(1966)(page 384) which states:

> Let $p$ be a prime and $m$ an even integer. If $(p-1)\nmid m$, then
>   $B_m$ is $p$-integral(that is, $p$ does not appear in the denominator
>   of $B_m$). If $(p-1) | m$, then $pB_m$ is $p$-integral, and $$pB_m
> \equiv -1 (mod\hspace{0.05in}p).$$

What's the meaning of this congruence? 
For instance for $p=3$ and $m=4,$ $3B_4=3(\frac{-1}{30})=\frac{-1}{10}.$ How is $$\frac{-1}{10} \equiv -1 (mod\hspace{0.05in}3) ?$$

Thank you!

Comment: You've put a greater-than symbol in your question, which makes it somewhat confusing.

Comment: @Prometheus, sorry, it was a mistake. I have a edited that now. Thanks.

Comment: @Prometheus, the second condition leading to the congruence is satisfied. In the first case, it is $B_m$ which is $p$-integral and in the second case, it is $pB_m$ which is $p$-integral. I will also be glad to know what a fraction means in congruence arithmetic.

Comment: Here is a related question(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363529/congruence-between-bernoulli-numbers?rq=1) and the comment under the first answer is my question. What's congruence in the ring of p-integrs? Do I have to use p-adic numbers?

Comment: If you mean the word $p$-integral in the statement of the theorem, it just means exactly what it says: $p$ does not appear in the denominator. For a correct statement of the theorem, with the right sign, see: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Von_Staudt-Clausen_theorem

Comment: Please ignore that comment. You don't need to know about $p$-adic numbers in order to do congruence arithmetic with fractions mod $p$, as long as the denomintor is $p$-integral. In any case even if you did, the answer and the method would be the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17162/discussion-between-holden-karl-and-prometheus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fraction $\frac{1}{n}$ is, *by definition*, the number which you can multiply $n$ by to get the answer $1$. Now the same definition works in congruence arithmetic. For example modulo $p$, as long as $n$ is not divisible by $p$ there is some number $m$ such that $nm \equiv 1$ mod $p$. In that case $\frac{1}{n}\equiv m$ (mod $p$).

There's a sign error in the statement of the theorem in that book. The formula for when $m|p-1$ (as you've now corrected) should be $pBm \equiv -1$ modulo $p$.

So for $m=4$ and $p=3$ we get $pB_4 = \frac{-1}{10} \equiv -1$ modulo 3, which makes sense since $10\equiv 1$ (mod $3$).

For another example let's look at $m=16$ and $p=5$, and $B_{16} = \frac{-3617}{510}$. We have

$$pB_m = 5 \frac{-3617}{510} = \frac{-3617}{102},$$

Now $102 \equiv 2$ (mod $5$), and $3*2 = 6 \equiv 1$, so $\frac{1}{102} \equiv 3$. We also have $-3617 \equiv -7 \equiv 3$ (mod $5$) and so indeed

$$pB_m = \frac{-3617}{102} \equiv \frac{3}{102} \equiv 3 * 3 = 9 \equiv -1 \text{(mod }5)$$